# Failed to connect to server during the uninstallation process

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-installer

I have an installation package (Visual studio installer). During the installation process i attach a database to MS Sql server using SMO.
When the uninstallation process is started the dialog "The following applications ("SQL server(MSSQLServer)") should be closed before continuing the install" appears. The dialog has two options "Automatically close applications and attempt to restart them after setup is complete" and "Do not close applications(A Reboot may be required)". if i select first one option, i see the error "cannot connect at server". With  the second option all works correctly. 
In the  unistall method of my custom action i use  SqlCommand (command text: DROP DATABASE [baseName]) for deleting database.
Uninstall method code:

```
using(var con=new SqlConnection(_server.ConnectionContext.ConnectionString))
          {
              con.Open();
              string sqlCommandText = string.Format("DROP DATABASE [{0}]", DATABASE_NAME);
              var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText, con);
              sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
```

How can i avoid the dialog "The following applications ..." and always use the second option?  Or maybe there i some other way for deleting db?